# Miglayout cell height with font too tall

Tags: java, miglayout

http://postimg.org/image/89g61o7jl/42b4a9b9/

In here you can see that the cell with 15 has few added pixels to the height of the cell. Now my question is how can I reduce the height of the cell to match the font like this http://s13.postimg.org/4qey77daf/how_i_would_like_it.png where it wraps the height of the cell to match the height of the component.

I'm asking this as the font size is becoming a problem with a layout I'm trying to do, and I would like to know how I can increase height of cell and decrease it so that I can control space between components.

Here is my source code :

```
package migtest;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;


public class somexamp extends JFrame{

    public somexamp()  {
        try {
            JPanel somepanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("debug,nogrid,flowy","",""));

            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("src/migtest/misty cloud or windy for land.png"));
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
            JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
            JLabel label2 = new JLabel("now");
            JLabel label3 = new JLabel("°C");
            JLabel label4 = new JLabel("15");

            Font tempf = new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 40);
            label4.setFont(tempf);


            JCheckBox somenexthing = new JCheckBox("Program argument");
            JButton jj = new JButton("Blah");
            JButton jm = new JButton("Blah2");
            somenexthing.setFont(new Font("Arial", 1, 10));
            jj.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 100));
            somepanel.add(label2,"");
            somepanel.add(label4,"");

            somepanel.add(label);
            this.setContentPane(somepanel);
            this.setSize(600, 400);

            this.setVisible(true);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(somexamp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new somexamp();
    }



}
```